# Lightweight CMS that lets me write markup

Tags: open-source, html, cms

I'm looking for a free/open source content management system that lets me write my own markup, CSS and JavaScript in my text editor - without including unnecessary modules and components,  but allows my client to write articles, blog, etc.

A good example for what I'd like, would be that I define an element (e.g. `<section class="content">`) in the markup where the new posts and articles, my customers write (e.g. in a WYSIWYG editor or Markdown format) would appear.

Just ordinary articles with a title and a body with text and images included. Meta tags would be nice but not absolutely necessary.